# How can I locate a string inside a span, using selenium

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im currently working on a project where both the class and the string in a span element is randomized. However the path is the same on the webpage. How can i print the string?

<!span unselectable="on" class="WubDRmeS">Come</span!>

The word I want is "Come".

```
def reader():
    text = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/span[1]")    
    print(text)
```

Comment: the span has exclamation mark `!` ?

Comment: The span has exclamation mark, cause when i wrote the question in stack overflow the whole line just said "Come"

Answer (score 0):

Just call method .text for your element `browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/span[1]").text`

Comment: I get an error saying 'str' object has no attribute 'text'